# Error occurred in deployment step. Cannot connect to the SharePoint site:

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-hosted-app

While creating a new App For Sharepoint, in Sharepoint Site URL Validation Form.

When we click the `Validate` Button the following error is shown:

> Cannot connect to the SharePoint site:'http://sample:16311/sites/DevCatalog/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that your Application Pool & SP Site are running in IIS.

> You will able to fix with the help of [this link](http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/19/resolving-vs-2010-solution-deployment-issues-for-sharepoint-2010-projects/)
>
> **Steps from the Site**
>
> 1. Check what user vssphost14.exe (or vssphost15.exe) is running as (Generally the same user you are using to run VS)
> 2. Launch SQL Management Studio and connect to your SharePoint SQl Instance
> 3. Ensure the above user has DB_Owner rights on each of the following databases:
>
>    ```
>    SharePoint_Config
>    SharePoint_AdminContent
>    Content DB for the Site collection you are deploying to
>    ```
> 4. You may need to restart VS
>
> *The above databases may have different names (GUIDs), but the config, admin, and content DBs are the ones you want*

Comment: is this helps you to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Hardik. It's Worked After Providing DB_Owner rights for mentioned databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Site URL in your VS Project properties with the web application URL in your CA > Manage Web Applications.

[image]

Comment: the following error is shown When we click the Validate Button. Already mentioned in question